# jQuery - dynamically change webkit-animate time parameter

Tags: jquery, webkit, keyframe

I need to make customizable the blink speed of a text

And I made in this way:

```
<style>
    .blink {
        -webkit-animation: blink 0s step-end infinite;
                animation: blink 0s step-end infinite;
     }
     @-webkit-keyframes blink { 50% { visibility: hidden; }}
     @keyframes blink { 50% { visibility: hidden; }}
</style>

<body>
    <div id="test" class="blink">Test</div>
    <input id="blinkspeed" type="number" value="0"> 
</body>


<script>
    $('#blinkspeed').click(function(){
        $("#test")[0].style.webkitAnimation = "blink "+$(this).val()+"s step-end infinite";
    });     
</script>
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bbc94sp9/) here

This blinks with Chrome but not with ff and ie (opera not tested)

Shall I consider that animation is not a standard and I have to write a line for each browser?

I added this

```
$("#test")[0].style.Animation = "blink "+blinkspeed+"s step-end infinite";
```

but nothing happened.

Can someone give me some hints please?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> this blinks with Chrome but not with ff and ie (opera not tested)

Try using `.text()` , `String.prototype.replace()` with `RegExp` `/\d+(?=s)/g` to match number followed by `"s"` , update `animation-duration` with `this.value` of `#blinkspeed`

```js
$("#blinkspeed").click(function() {
  var blinkspeed = this.value;
  $("style").text(function(_, style) {
    return style.replace(/\d+(?=s)/g, blinkspeed)
  })
});
```

```css
.blink {
  -webkit-animation: blink 0s step-end infinite;
  -moz-animation: blink 0s step-end infinite;
  -ms-animation:  blink 0s step-end infinite;
  animation: blink 0s step-end infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes blink {
  50% {
    visibility: hidden;
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes blink {
  50% {
    visibility: hidden;
  }
}

@-ms-keyframes blink {
  50% {
    visibility: hidden;
  }
}

@keyframes blink {
  50% {
    visibility: hidden;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>

<body>
  <div id="test" class="blink">Test</div>
  <input id="blinkspeed" type="number" value="0">
</body>
```

jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/bbc94sp9/6/

Comment: Hi guest 271314!
thanks for the solution for ff.. but here many still use ie :-( I tried with 'animation' only but...
tks!

Comment: hi!
Thanks..I saw changes, but on ie11 does not work, neither in this page :-(
Anyway, thanks a lot for the efforts

Regards